# Divide Paypal Standard Payments to two separate accounts

Tags: paypal

I have a Paypal Standard gateway set up which pays the business account specified in the input no problem. I would like to make it so that at the same time, the customer is also paying a fee to the website - so they're paying our Paypal account a fee.

E.g. User buys a product (clicks Buy Now)

Goes to Paypal screen, and when the customer confirms the payment it will send the following money:

- **£10** - to the sellers account
- **£1.50** - to our account (fee)

I've heard a few methods such as Chain payments, Parallel payments and x.com says Adaptive payments, but I've not been able to understand the best method for doing this with a Paypal Standard integration.

Can someone point me in the right direction with this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do You Know the Answer?? if so please share with us?

Comment: I ended up outsourcing to a developer who wrote a script using Parallell payments. You first need to apply for a Paypal developer key: https://www.x.com/products/access/applications/submit which only takes a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Adaptive Payments is a general term for the API's that handle this sort of thing.  Chained Payments and Parallel Payments are under that same umbrella, so to speak.

Both chained and parallel payments will split your payment between multiple accounts like you're after.  The primary difference is that the payer will see the split during checkout with a parallel payment, but you can hide that with a chained payment.  You can also delay the secondary payment(s) using a chained setup.

If you happen to be working with PHP I'd recommend using my [PHP class library for PayPal](http://www.angelleye.com/overview-of-php-class-library-for-paypal/), which will make all of this very simple for you.  I even offer 30 min of free training if you need help getting started, which is generally plenty of time to get you going if you understand how to work with array data.

Comment: Interesting concept. Does PayPal deduct its fees from both transactions (buyer to seller and 'our account') so to speak, or only from the main transaction (buyer to seller)?

Comment: Well, you have the option for that actually, but unfortunately Adaptive Payments is deprecated.  It's possible to get them to enable it for you under specific circumstances, but you'd have to go through PayPal MTS to get it enabled.  Then you could do everything I mentioned here.

Beyond that, they are introducing the new Orders v2 APIs, which will be a replacement for what Adaptive Payments did.  It's only available to select partners right now, though, so you won't be able to use it for a while.